# ajax jquery adding data problems

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

Hi I have products in repeater And I want to add them to basket

here is button ;

```
<asp:Button ID="sepeteEkle" runat="server" Text="EklEPanpa" class="sepetat"  data-id=<%#Eval ("Id") %>    OnClientClick="sepet(); return false; " />
```

I run this script;

```
     function sepeteEkle(id) {

         var urunid = id;
         var GirenIp = $("#userId").val();
         $.ajax({
             dataType: "json",
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json",
             url: "/Admin/WebService/Control.asmx/calistir",
             data: "{'urunid':'" + urunid + "','GirenIp':'" + GirenIp + "' }",
             success: function(){
                 $("#cartContent").load("MiniSepet.aspx #cartContent");
             },
             error: function () {
                 $("#cartContent").load("MiniSepet.aspx #cartContent");
             }
         });
         return false;
     }
     function sepet() {
         $(".sepetat").on("click", function () {
             var nId = $(this).data("id")
             sepeteEkle(nId);

         })
     }
```

and this sends to the webservice

```
[WebMethod]

    public void calistir(int urunid, string GirenIp)
    {
        using (Models.DermabonEntities db = new Models.DermabonEntities())
        {


            var productName = (from i in db.Product
                               where i.Id == urunid
                               select i.ProductName).FirstOrDefault();
            var productPrice = (from i in db.Product
                                where i.Id == urunid
                                select i.ProductPrice).FirstOrDefault();

            var productId = (from i in db.Product
                             where i.Id == urunid
                             select i.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            var productPic = (from i in db.Product
                              where i.Id == urunid
                              select i.ProductPicture).FirstOrDefault();

            var userIp = GirenIp;

            Basket create = new Basket();

            create.ProductName = productName;
            create.ProductId = productId;
            create.ProductPrice = productPrice;
            create.ProductPic = productPic;
            create.UserId = userIp;



            db.Basket.Add(create);
            db.SaveChanges();




        }

    }
```

So I get Product Id with ajax to send it into webservice and I add product name and things to server by this way. But the problem is when i click on any item button in repeater it doesnt add. with my second click it adds 2 rows. And I click on a different product button it adds 3 row then 4 row and it goes like this. But i click 1 time for every button. What should i do to fix this ?

Comment: i think `asp:Button` does not have `class` attribute , use `CssClass` instead

Comment: @Amit Soni: The fact that he is getting results (just duplicated) implies this is not the case.

Comment: @user3702153 +1 for providing code and HTML and a good description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you are adding a click handler to every single element with `class="sepetat"` every time you press the button. This results in the new handler being added over and over on every element, hence the number of rows added increases with use.

You just need a single *delegated event* handler connected once:

```
     $(document).on('click', '.sepetat', function () {
         var nId = $(this).data("id")
         sepeteEkle(nId);
     });
```

and get rid of the OnClientClick attribute of your button (jQuery does not need you to push the click event):

```
<asp:Button ID="sepeteEkle" runat="server" Text="EklEPanpa" class="sepetat"  data-id=<%#Eval ("Id") %> />
```

Delegated events listen at an ancestor, *then* apply the selector, *then* apply the function to any matching elements that generated the event.

The preference is to use the first non-changing ancestor in your DOM. Failing that (you do not show the rest of the page) you can use `document` which receives all bubbled events on the page.

Comment: thank you it worked. but now the page refreshes every time i click the button so I wait a lot to add item. How can I stop the refresh the whole page?

Comment: Probable cause is the button with `RunAt="server"`. Just make it a raw HTML button as you don't need the rest of the server-side features. If not, you need to disable whatever is causing a postback. Can you provide the HTML of the *output of the page* and not just the ASP source code? Then I can identify the cause of the postback.

Comment: I dont need server-side And I just put a input button and it worked. Can you tell me is there any code that goes to top of the page i mean slides to top of the page with that input button click. And also change the visibilty of a div

Comment: Sounds like new questions, but `$(window).scrollTop(0)` should take you straight to the top of the page.You need to `.animate` the `scrollTop` property to smooth scroll it. Use jQuery's `.hide()` and `.show()` methods on the div to hide and show it (or `.css("visibility", "none")`)

Comment: Don't forget the little up arrow and tick etc if you are happy with the answer above :)